# prepareForSegue not executed

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've a storyboard (xcode5) with an embedded navigation controller (the navigation controller points into my main view controller).

I've created a segue name to a new view controller which I want to open through my code.

```
[[self navigationController] performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueTo" sender:self];


- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
     NSLog(@"Segue");
}
```

The view controller do open up but the prepareForSegue will never run, why?

I've tried with

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueTo" sender:self];
```

but then I get an runtime error saying it can't find the segue name.

Comment: Did you actually set the name of the segue in interface builder?

Comment: Yes I did, but wrongly. I made the connection from the navigation controller and not from the main view controller. Now when I made modal connection from the main view controller it works :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue you are trying to perform must be linked from `viewcontroller1` (embedded in navigation controller) to `newviewcontroller`. In storyboard, make sure you have named connecting segue as **"segueTo"**. Then in `viewcontroller1`, call:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueTo" sender:self];
```

instead of:

```
[[self navigationController] performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueTo" sender:self];
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
[[self navigationController] performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueTo" sender:self];
```

with

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueTo" sender:self];
```

It should help.

Comment: yes that works, but I had to make a proper connection from main view controller and the new view controller. I did it first from the navigation controller which was wrong.